# Bringing up galera cluster

Tags: mariadb, galera

Because of a mismanagement I have a 3 node cluster down. Before doing the due diligence disregarding `seqno` and recovery processes, the node that used to be the primary was brought up doing `galera_new_cluster` forcing `safe_to_bootstrap: 1`.

Now, I have this:

Node 1 (up) grastate.dat

```
# GALERA saved state
version: 2.1
uuid:    966697b0-f645-11e9-9826-7fcf25dc378a
seqno:   -1
safe_to_bootstrap: 1
```

```
wsrep_local_state_comment   Synced
wsrep_cluster_size  1
wsrep_cluster_status    Primary
```

Node 2 (down) grastate.dat

```
# GALERA saved state
version: 2.1
uuid:    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
seqno:   -1
safe_to_bootstrap: 0
```

Node 3 (down) grastate.dat

```
# GALERA saved state
version: 2.1
uuid:    00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
seqno:   -1
safe_to_bootstrap: 0
```

When I try to bring up node 2, I get the following in the logs of node 1:

```
Member 0.0 (coredb-02) requested state transfer from '*any*'. Selected 1.0 (coredb-01)(SYNCED) as donor.
Shifting SYNCED -> DONOR/DESYNCED
```

And then eventually node 2 fails.

When I try to bring up node 3, I get the following (many times) in the logs of node 1:

```
WSREP: Member 1.0 (coredb-03) requested state transfer from '*any*', but it is impossible to select State Transfer donor: Resource temporarily unavailable
```

And then eventually node 3 fails.

At this point, I don't care about the latest data as this DB doesn't have frequent updates. Just want to bring the cluster up.

If I'm missing important info please let me know.

Logs on node 2:

```
Feb 27 21:29:46 coredb-02 systemd: Starting MariaDB 10.4.28 database server...
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 sh: WSREP: Recovered position 966697b0-f645-11e9-9826-7fcf25dc378a:966010
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:48 0 [Note] Starting MariaDB 10.4.28-MariaDB source revision c8f2e9a5c0ac5905f28b050b7df5a9ffd914b7e7 as process 31044
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:48 0 [Note] WSREP: Loading provider /usr/lib64/galera-4/libgalera_smm.so initial position: 966697b0-f645-11e9-9826-7fcf25dc378a:966010
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:48 0 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): loading provider library '/usr/lib64/galera-4/libgalera_smm.so'
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:48 0 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_load(): Galera 26.4.14(r06a0c28) by Codership Oy <info@codership.com> loaded successfully.
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:48 0 [Note] WSREP: CRC-32C: using 64-bit x86 acceleration.
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:48 0 [Note] WSREP: Found saved state: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1, safe_to_bootstrap: 0
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:48 0 [Note] WSREP: GCache DEBUG: opened preamble:
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: Version: 2
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: UUID: 966697b0-f645-11e9-9826-7fcf25dc378a
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: Seqno: -1 - -1
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: Offset: -1
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: Synced: 0
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:48 0 [Note] WSREP: Recovering GCache ring buffer: version: 2, UUID: 966697b0-f645-11e9-9826-7fcf25dc378a, offset: -1
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:48 0 [Note] WSREP: GCache::RingBuffer initial scan...  0.0% (        0/134217752 bytes) complete.
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:48 0 [Note] WSREP: GCache::RingBuffer initial scan...100.0% (134217752/134217752 bytes) complete.
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:48 0 [Note] WSREP: Recovering GCache ring buffer: Recovery failed, need to do full reset.
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:48 0 [Note] WSREP: Passing config to GCS: base_dir = /var/lib/mysql/; base_host = 10.132.24.199; base_port = 4567; cert.log_conflicts = no; cert.optimistic_pa = yes; debug = no; evs.auto_evict = 0; evs.delay_margin = PT1S; evs.delayed_keep_period = PT30S; evs.inactive_check_period = PT0.5S; evs.inactive_timeout = PT15S; evs.join_retrans_period = PT1S; evs.max_install_timeouts = 3; evs.send_window = 4; evs.stats_report_period = PT1M; evs.suspect_timeout = PT5S; evs.user_send_window = 2; evs.view_forget_timeout = PT24H; gcache.dir = /var/lib/mysql/; gcache.keep_pages_size = 0; gcache.keep_plaintext_size = 128M; gcache.mem_size = 0; gcache.name = galera.cache; gcache.page_size = 128M; gcache.recover = yes; gcache.size = 128M; gcomm.thread_prio = ; gcs.fc_debug = 0; gcs.fc_factor = 1.0; gcs.fc_limit = 16; gcs.fc_master_slave = no; gcs.fc_single_primary = no; gcs.max_packet_size = 64500; gcs.max_throttle = 0.25; gcs.recv_q_hard_limit = 9223372036854775807; gcs.recv_q_soft_limit = 0.25; gcs.sync_donor = no; gmcast.segment = 0
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:48 0 [Note] WSREP: Start replication
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:48 0 [Note] WSREP: Connecting with bootstrap option: 0
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:48 0 [Note] WSREP: Setting GCS initial position to 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:48 0 [Note] WSREP: Using CRC-32C for message checksums.
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:48 0 [Note] WSREP: backend: asio
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:48 0 [Note] WSREP: gcomm thread scheduling priority set to other:0
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:48 0 [Note] WSREP: access file(/var/lib/mysql//gvwstate.dat) failed(No such file or directory)
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:48 0 [Note] WSREP: restore pc from disk failed
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:48 0 [Note] WSREP: GMCast version 0
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:48 0 [Note] WSREP: (dcea5e6e-8801, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') listening at tcp://0.0.0.0:4567
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:48 0 [Note] WSREP: (dcea5e6e-8801, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') multicast: , ttl: 1
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:48 0 [Note] WSREP: EVS version 1
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:48 0 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: connecting to group 'core_xxxxxxx_cluster', peer '10.132.23.190:,10.132.24.199:,10.132.15.197:'
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:48 0 [Note] WSREP: (dcea5e6e-8801, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') Found matching local endpoint for a connection, blacklisting address tcp://10.132.24.199:4567
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:48 0 [Note] WSREP: (dcea5e6e-8801, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') connection established to b7fcc4f3-a931 tcp://10.132.23.190:4567
Feb 27 21:29:48 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:48 0 [Note] WSREP: (dcea5e6e-8801, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning message relay requesting on, nonlive peers:
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 0 [Note] WSREP: EVS version upgrade 0 -> 1
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 0 [Note] WSREP: declaring b7fcc4f3-a931 at tcp://10.132.23.190:4567 stable
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 0 [Note] WSREP: PC protocol upgrade 0 -> 1
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 0 [Note] WSREP: Node b7fcc4f3-a931 state prim
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 0 [Note] WSREP: view(view_id(PRIM,b7fcc4f3-a931,101) memb {
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: b7fcc4f3-a931,0
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: dcea5e6e-8801,0
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: } joined {
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: } left {
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: } partitioned {
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: })
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 0 [Note] WSREP: save pc into disk
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 0 [Note] WSREP: discarding pending addr without UUID: tcp://10.132.15.197:4567
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 0 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: connected
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 0 [Note] WSREP: Changing maximum packet size to 64500, resulting msg size: 32636
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 0 [Note] WSREP: Shifting CLOSED -> OPEN (TO: 0)
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 0 [Note] WSREP: Opened channel 'core_xxxxxxx_cluster'
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 0 [Note] WSREP: New COMPONENT: primary = yes, bootstrap = no, my_idx = 1, memb_num = 2
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 0 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: Waiting for state UUID.
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 0 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: sent state msg: dd3848bb-b6e5-11ed-af07-275aea34fa8c
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 0 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: dd3848bb-b6e5-11ed-af07-275aea34fa8c from 0 (coredb-01.xxxxxxx.com)
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 1 [Note] WSREP: Starting rollbacker thread 1
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 2 [Note] WSREP: Starting applier thread 2
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 0 [Note] WSREP: STATE EXCHANGE: got state msg: dd3848bb-b6e5-11ed-af07-275aea34fa8c from 1 (coredb-02.xxxxxxx.com)
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 0 [Note] WSREP: Quorum results:
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: version    = 6,
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: component  = PRIMARY,
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: conf_id    = 98,
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: members    = 1/2 (joined/total),
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: act_id     = 966619,
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: last_appl. = 966459,
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: protocols  = 2/10/4 (gcs/repl/appl),
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: vote policy= 0,
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: group UUID = 966697b0-f645-11e9-9826-7fcf25dc378a
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 0 [Note] WSREP: Flow-control interval: [23, 23]
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 0 [Note] WSREP: Shifting OPEN -> PRIMARY (TO: 966620)
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 2 [Note] WSREP: ####### processing CC 966620, local, ordered
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 2 [Note] WSREP: Process first view: 966697b0-f645-11e9-9826-7fcf25dc378a my uuid: dcea5e6e-b6e5-11ed-8801-b71890fbe1d8
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 2 [Note] WSREP: Server coredb-02.xxxxxxx.com connected to cluster at position 966697b0-f645-11e9-9826-7fcf25dc378a:966620 with ID dcea5e6e-b6e5-11ed-8801-b71890fbe1d8
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 2 [Note] WSREP: Server status change disconnected -> connected
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 2 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 2 [Note] WSREP: ####### My UUID: dcea5e6e-b6e5-11ed-8801-b71890fbe1d8
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 2 [Note] WSREP: Cert index reset to 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1 (proto: 10), state transfer needed: yes
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 0 [Note] WSREP: Service thread queue flushed.
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 2 [Note] WSREP: ####### Assign initial position for certification: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1, protocol version: -1
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 2 [Note] WSREP: State transfer required:
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: Group state: 966697b0-f645-11e9-9826-7fcf25dc378a:966620
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: Local state: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000:-1
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 2 [Note] WSREP: Server status change connected -> joiner
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 2 [Note] WSREP: wsrep_notify_cmd is not defined, skipping notification.
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 0 [Note] WSREP: Joiner monitor thread started to monitor
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:49 0 [Note] WSREP: Running: 'wsrep_sst_rsync --role 'joiner' --address '10.132.24.199' --datadir '/var/lib/mysql/' --parent 31044 --progress 0 --mysqld-args --wsrep_start_position=966697b0-f645-11e9-9826-7fcf25dc378a:966010'
Feb 27 21:29:49 coredb-02 mysqld: WSREP_SST: [INFO] rsync SST started on joiner (20230227 21:29:49.901)
Feb 27 21:29:50 coredb-02 rsyncd[31183]: rsyncd version 3.1.2 starting, listening on port 4444
Feb 27 21:29:50 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:50 2 [Note] WSREP: ####### IST uuid:00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000 f: 0, l: 966620, STRv: 3
Feb 27 21:29:50 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:50 2 [Note] WSREP: IST receiver addr using tcp://10.132.24.199:4568
Feb 27 21:29:50 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:50 2 [Note] WSREP: Prepared IST receiver for 0-966620, listening at: tcp://10.132.24.199:4568
Feb 27 21:29:50 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:50 0 [Note] WSREP: Member 1.0 (coredb-02.xxxxxxx.com) requested state transfer from '*any*'. Selected 0.0 (coredb-01.xxxxxxx.com)(SYNCED) as donor.
Feb 27 21:29:50 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:50 0 [Note] WSREP: Shifting PRIMARY -> JOINER (TO: 966620)
Feb 27 21:29:50 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:50 2 [Note] WSREP: Requesting state transfer: success, donor: 0
Feb 27 21:29:50 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:50 2 [Note] WSREP: Resetting GCache seqno map due to different histories.
Feb 27 21:29:50 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:50 2 [Note] WSREP: GCache history reset: 966697b0-f645-11e9-9826-7fcf25dc378a:0 -> 966697b0-f645-11e9-9826-7fcf25dc378a:966620
Feb 27 21:29:52 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:29:52 0 [Note] WSREP: (dcea5e6e-8801, 'tcp://0.0.0.0:4567') turning message relay requesting off
Feb 27 21:31:31 coredb-02 systemd-logind: Removed session 1.
Feb 27 21:31:31 coredb-02 systemd: Removed slice User Slice of virtuale.
Feb 27 21:31:57 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:31:57 0 [Warning] WSREP: 0.0 (coredb-01.xxxxxxx.com): State transfer to 1.0 (coredb-02.xxxxxxx.com) failed: -110 (Connection timed out)
Feb 27 21:31:57 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:31:57 0 [ERROR] WSREP: /home/buildbot/buildbot/build/gcs/src/gcs_group.cpp:gcs_group_handle_join_msg():1207: Will never receive state. Need to abort.
Feb 27 21:31:57 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:31:57 0 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: terminating thread
Feb 27 21:31:57 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:31:57 0 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: joining thread
Feb 27 21:31:57 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:31:57 0 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: closing backend
Feb 27 21:31:58 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:31:58 0 [Note] WSREP: view(view_id(NON_PRIM,b7fcc4f3-a931,101) memb {
Feb 27 21:31:58 coredb-02 mysqld: dcea5e6e-8801,0
Feb 27 21:31:58 coredb-02 mysqld: } joined {
Feb 27 21:31:58 coredb-02 mysqld: } left {
Feb 27 21:31:58 coredb-02 mysqld: } partitioned {
Feb 27 21:31:58 coredb-02 mysqld: b7fcc4f3-a931,0
Feb 27 21:31:58 coredb-02 mysqld: })
Feb 27 21:31:58 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:31:58 0 [Note] WSREP: PC protocol downgrade 1 -> 0
Feb 27 21:31:58 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:31:58 0 [Note] WSREP: view((empty))
Feb 27 21:31:58 coredb-02 systemd: mariadb.service: main process exited, code=killed, status=6/ABRT
Feb 27 21:31:58 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:31:58 0 [Note] WSREP: gcomm: closed
Feb 27 21:31:58 coredb-02 mysqld: 2023-02-27 21:31:58 0 [Note] WSREP: /usr/sbin/mysqld: Terminated.
Feb 27 21:31:58 coredb-02 mysqld: Terminated
Feb 27 21:31:58 coredb-02 mysqld: WSREP_SST: [ERROR] Cleanup after exit with status: 3 (20230227 21:31:58.442)
Feb 27 21:31:58 coredb-02 mysqld: WSREP_SST: [INFO] Joiner cleanup: rsync PID=31183, stunnel PID=0 (20230227 21:31:58.447)
Feb 27 21:31:58 coredb-02 rsyncd[31183]: sent 0 bytes  received 0 bytes  total size 0
Feb 27 21:31:58 coredb-02 mysqld: WSREP_SST: [INFO] Joiner cleanup done. (20230227 21:31:58.977)
Feb 27 21:31:58 coredb-02 systemd: Failed to start MariaDB 10.4.28 database server.
Feb 27 21:31:58 coredb-02 systemd: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
Feb 27 21:31:58 coredb-02 systemd: mariadb.service failed.
Feb 27 21:32:04 coredb-02 systemd: mariadb.service holdoff time over, scheduling restart.
Feb 27 21:32:04 coredb-02 systemd: Stopped MariaDB 10.4.28 database server.
```

Comment: edit question to show node1 and node2 logs from the moment the SST started. MariaDB and galera version would be useful to put into the question.

Comment: I have included the logs of one of the nodes. Right now, I have the cluster down and operating as a single node.

Comment: looks like a connection errors between the nodes - check https://galeracluster.com/library/documentation/firewall-settings.html

Comment: Thanks, never occurred to me that different ports were used for that. I have opened those ports in the firewall. 

Now, maybe it's a silly question, since then, node 1 (has been running as standalone, no cluster, wsrep_on=OFF). If I stop node 1, execute galera_new_cluster (wsrep_on=ON) and then start node 2, then node 3 (after node 2 finishes), all the data in node 1 would be replicated (that simple)? Thanks again!

Comment: That sounds like the right recovery mechanism

Answer (score 0):

Starting node 2, you expect node 1 to go into a donor mode. More logs are however required to determine why this didn't complete.

On node 3 failing to start, I suspect its failing because node 1 is still a donor. Important thing to note, due to belligerence from Codership (galera developers), the "Resource temporarily unavailable" isn't actually a system error, its something they used internally as EAGAIN and expect you to magically work it out. Attempts to fix to use meaningful error messages have been [futile](https://github.com/codership/galera/pull/109).

Comment: Thanks for your insight. At this stage and considering I'm OK with the latest data on node 1. Could I just "relaunch" the cluster as it was a new one? I mean, "ditching" the data on node 2 and 3? Just want to be sure I don't oversee any roadblock or risk the integrity of the data in node 1 if I go that road.

Comment: once you have explicitly made a primary on node 1 that's effectively what you have done. node 2/3 know they are out of date when they join and begin to SST. Edit question with more detailed logs because knowing why these SST don't finish is important.

Comment: Thanks again! Sorry for the delay. I have included the logs of one of the nodes. Right now, I have the cluster down and operating as a single node.